# Style a clicked link - Any CSS only solution?

Tags: css, hyperlink, click

Is there any `CSS` only solution to style a **clicked** `link`, which could provide feedback to the user, that the `link` has been **clicked** and its taking the desired action.

---

I could use `JavaScript` listen to `click` event and a desired class to provide feedback. However a `CSS` only feedback will be better if any.

Any pointer would be of great help.

Something like below is desired.

[image: link feedback demo]

Please refer this [pen](http://codepen.io/sarbbottam/pen/QjyJrE) for a working demo/simulation of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult using `a` element to made something like this to works using CSS only across different browsers.

Here is workaround that can give you the expected result using a `radio` button.

If you make a hidden radio button with an associated label style just like a link. You could use CSS pseudo `:checked` to give a desired result.

Code like this:

```css
input[type=radio] {
    display:none
}

input[type=radio] + label {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    color:red
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    content:url('https://forums.adobe.com/images/jive-image-loading.gif')
}
```

```html
  <input type="radio" value="" id="myRadio" />
  <label for="myRadio">
      Click me!
  </label>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z9p4gL0/)

============ **Below is my answer before updated OP** ============

`a` element in css have many pseudo selectors.
You can use them to know if the link gets hovered, has been clicked, is clicked right now.

There are 4 link states:

`a:link    - a normal, unvisited link`

`a:visited - a link the user has visited`

`a:hover   - a link when the user mouses over it`

`a:active  - a link the moment it is clicked`

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efx8387w/) to view those different selectors in action

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but thats not what I am looking for. `:active` is the most closed one, but does not address the requirement. Requirement is to style a clicked link. May be show a spinner after the link has been clicked, or change the color. `:active`, `:visited`, `:hover` does not address the desired behavior.

Comment: @cocoa update the OP, do you thing still consider `:visited` will be be useful?

Comment: no, i see that your situation is a bit more complicated

Comment: @morgul, nice +1 for the solution, but I guess JS solution would be more cleaner than this. I would not prefer to update the structure, just for the sake of the presentation.

Comment: Accepted the answer as it address the OP, but I am going ahead with JS based solution.